# BackGround image doesn't render when i change right to left layout

Tags: c#

I have set a backGround image for my form and set **right to left** property to **No** and also **right to left layout** to **false** and trying to change these with a button, but when i click button i doesn't render and backGround is white.(Windows form C#).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that we can't set an image when the form set right to left layout, but one way is to  trick user to see a picture. with a panel dock to fill and set an image background for the panel user will only see the picture. check the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnl.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:\\Picture\\Graphic\\2\\(1).png");//address of your image
            pnl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

For the `Form.RightToLeftLayout` Property:

> BackgroundImage, Opacity, TransparencyKey, and the painting events are not supported.